# How to get Certificate Chain to Show on Google Chrome

Tags: ssl, tomcat, certificate, ssl-certificate, chain

I have a root certificate that signs an intermediate certificate that signs a server certificate.

I tried two things:

1. Importing the original server certificate into a keystore and directing the tomcat server to use it via applications.properties. This is what shows up in the Google Chrome browser.

[image: Certificate Display on Google Chrome]

2. I thought that I needed to somehow bundle up the certificates so I read how to do it from [this](https://support.vidyocloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000460374-Combining-Root-and-Intermediate-Certificates#:%7E:text=To%20combine%20them%2C%20simply%20copy,end%20of%20the%20new%20filename.) website, which said:
   [image: instructions for bundling up certificates]
   So, I imported the content from my intermediate key and appended it to the original server certificate file, and then also added the contents of the root certificate file to the original server certificate file, and saved it. Then I replaced the old entry of the server certificate that I already had in the keystore with this newly modified file.

I still get this image from Google Chrome:
[image: Certificate Display on Google Chrome]

I want the certificate display to show the certificate chain, such as this:
[image: Google Certificate Chain Display on Google Chrome]

Edit: Here is the output of keytool -list -v -keystore $ksfile

> Keystore type: PKCS12 Keystore provider: SUN
>
> Your keystore contains 1 entry
>
> Alias name: localhost Creation date: Aug 20, 2021 Entry type:
> PrivateKeyEntry Certificate chain length: 3 Certificate[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rai3.png): Owner:
> CN=localhost, O=Bash, L=NYC, C=US Issuer: CN=inter, O=Bash, L=NYC,
> C=US Serial number: b98987ce22901fab3491a5ad154b347acb7921b Valid
> from: Fri Aug 20 04:30:05 EDT 2021 until: Sat Aug 20 04:30:05 EDT 2022
> Certificate fingerprints:      SHA1:
> 0E:DC:9E:57:E9:AE:DA:3D:6A:43:8B:4C:0A:33:F8:51:6D:B0:B9:40    SHA256:
> 74:D1:67:00:C1:38:AB:21:A1:85:BA:2F:F5:51:91:92:6B:C6:91:F4:EB:F0:A7:9E:52:B2:F4:EB:A7:F7:63:A4
> Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA Subject Public Key Algorithm:
> 4096-bit RSA key Version: 3
>
> Extensions:
>
> #1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false ExtendedKeyUsages [   serverAuth ]
>
> #2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false SubjectAlternativeName [   DNSName: localhost   IPAddress: 192.168.0.10   IPAddress: 127.0.0.1 ]
>
> Certificate[2](https://support.vidyocloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000460374-Combining-Root-and-Intermediate-Certificates#:%7E:text=To%20combine%20them%2C%20simply%20copy,end%20of%20the%20new%20filename.): Owner: CN=inter, O=Bash, L=NYC, C=US Issuer: CN=ca,
> O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=AU Serial number:
> 26881cd1d803489c8956034f81f43ddd8a0fd593 Valid from: Fri Aug 20
> 04:27:40 EDT 2021 until: Sat Aug 20 04:27:40 EDT 2022 Certificate
> fingerprints:      SHA1:
> 08:CA:5C:76:E8:9F:FC:BA:0D:36:B6:C3:90:1C:0A:0B:C6:97:FF:BB    SHA256:
> 96:14:FF:E5:1A:D9:AA:ED:90:25:4B:56:D8:34:BD:94:27:1C:F2:29:24:1C:40:F2:D8:E4:25:5F:96:7E:2C:88
> Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA Subject Public Key Algorithm:
> 4096-bit RSA key Version: 3
>
> Extensions:
>
> #1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false ExtendedKeyUsages [   serverAuth ]
>
> #2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false SubjectAlternativeName [   DNSName: inter   IPAddress: 192.168.0.10   IPAddress: 127.0.0.1 ]
>
> Certificate[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj0Bv.png): Owner: CN=ca, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,
> ST=Some-State, C=AU Issuer: CN=ca, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,
> ST=Some-State, C=AU Serial number:
> 27018395ed4f99502a78393ac438e6cee90dcaf6 Valid from: Fri Aug 20
> 04:24:47 EDT 2021 until: Sat Aug 20 04:24:47 EDT 2022 Certificate
> fingerprints:      SHA1:
> 9A:35:88:C7:B3:E4:1D:02:17:F9:52:7F:32:95:D5:75:DF:E1:92:F3    SHA256:
> 92:BF:BC:20:C7:2B:65:6B:CE:D7:89:9B:02:2A:3E:0E:E3:7B:A9:AA:BF:FF:25:AE:9C:DC:FC:A1:60:48:7C:94
> Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA Subject Public Key Algorithm:
> 4096-bit RSA key Version: 3
>
> Extensions:
>
> #1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false AuthorityKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 66 A6 FA 5A 66 1E B7 74   55 6A 39 52 0B 37 2F
> 30  f..Zf..tUj9R.7/0 0010: 10 E1 FD D4
> .... ] ]
>
> #2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true BasicConstraints:[   CA:true   PathLen:2147483647 ]
>
> #3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false SubjectKeyIdentifier [ KeyIdentifier [ 0000: 66 A6 FA 5A 66 1E B7 74   55 6A 39 52 0B 37 2F
> 30  f..Zf..tUj9R.7/0 0010: 10 E1 FD D4
> .... ] ]
>
> ---
>
> ---

Comment: Use `keytool -list -v -keystore $ksfile` to see whether what you have in the keystore is correct, or if you prefer a GUI download https://keystore-explorer.org/ and use that. If the keystore is correct, make sure your tomcat is using it correctly, i.e. has been restarted and points to the correct file and entry (alias). And make sure your root cert is in _Chrome's_ truststore.

Answer (score 1):

As @dave_thompson_085 suggested, I downloaded [keystore-explorer.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867455/how-to-get-certificate-chain-to-show-on-google-chrome?noredirect=1#:%7E:text=keystore-explorer.org) and used the GUI to import the intermediate certificate into the keystore, which then caused the entire chain to show up on the browser. I only have one intermediate certificate so that is the only one that I had to import. The root certificate is installed on my system.